# Servlet: some issue with getting user directory

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Java servlet from which I need to access some files from my home directory. I use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` but then I get Tomcat's directory.

But I need my `user.dir` in the sense of `"/home/iangalesco"`, not Tomcat's `user.dir`. Is it possible to do?

Comment: How would the code running under the tomcat user, know the person at the end of the keyboard is `iangalesco`?  if you can let your java code know, then it should be possible.

Comment: So I have to do it by myself sth like: `myServlet.setCustomHomeDir("/home/iagalesco")` ?

Comment: Do you realize that Java code runs at the physical machine where the webserver runs and not at the physical machine where the webbrowser runs? Basically, Java/JSP/Servlet/etc run at webserver, generates a bunch of HTML/CSS/JS/whatnot, sends it to the webbrowser which in turn runs all that HTML stuff. If you really want to run Java code on the webbrowser via a HTML page for some unclear reason, use JNLP (or legacy Applet, but those are officious deprecated these days (and [will](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289) be deprecated in the future)).